# Open an URL followed by a hash sign using location.href or similar

Tags: javascript, fragment-identifier

There is a page with a "share at whatsapp" button. This creates and executes an URL like:

> whatsapp://send?text=Some text followed by a link - http://link_to_this_page**#something**

The problem is that the browser (I've tested only with Chrome for now) automatically deletes from the hash sign to onwards.

I have tried the basic:

```
var href = 'whatsapp://send?text=Example text - ';
var uri = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '#gm.';
location.href = href + uri;
```

I tried too with `location.replace()`, `location.assign()` and `window.open()` with no luck.

So the question is, how can I do? It's imperative to use the hash because it tells to the target page that it has to do some things in javascript (which could take more time to change).

Comment: `document.location.href = "your url" + window.location.hash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be encoding anything that is in the query string.

```
location.href = href + encodeURIComponent(uri);
```

You probably should be doing:

```
var href = 'whatsapp://send?text=';
var text = 'Example text - ';
var uri = location.protocol + '//' + location.host + location.pathname + '#gm.';
location.href = href + encodeURIComponent(text + uri);
```

Comment: Oh, sure!. I didn't realize on that. Thank you mate.